# Pass Ajax Variable value to html element in different page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

How can I pass data from a query in php and set it's result using an ajax method.
Here is what I have so far in a file called file1.php:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function myAjax () {
        $.ajax( { type : 'POST',
          data : { },
          url  : 'query.php',
          success: function ( data ) {
            $doc = new DomDocument();
            $doc->Load('file2.php');
            $element = $doc->getElementById('resultFromFile1');

          },
          error: function ( xhr ) {
            alert( "error" );
          }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I wanna put the contents in this html element in the php file file2.php:

```
          <p id ="resultFromFile1" name = "results">No Results</p>
```

Many stack overflow posts haven't been any help. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: So if I understand, you want to edit content of `file2.php` via AJAX ?
Your `php code` in `success callback` won't work because this function is called in browser, therefore you cannot run php this way

Comment: Why are you mixing JS with PHP? Are you trying to write to the file?

Comment: Indeed. I want to get the data that is in ajax and be able to pass that data's value in my file2.php

Comment: Well because my php has the queried information from my mysql database

Comment: The approach is flawed. Keep server side processing for the servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's wrong approach.
You should rather create php script which will save your ajax request data in let's say database and then in `file2.php` load this data from DB, **not directly** update file

Comment: Well when I clicked a button that was written in html, i set that button to retrieve the ajax method and  it was able to load the information that I was retrieving from my php code. I just wanted this to be replicated onto a different page instead of the same page where the button was

Comment: But AJAX request doesn't modify HTML forever. It's modified just in that one page relation, when you refresh page you get old html again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all what kind of content is query.php returning? Is it a JSON Object or are you just "echoing" the output as a string?

Next Question: Are you using jQuery, AngularJS or something in that direction?

Usually what you want to do is get the information from the "query.php" and pass it as a JSON formatted ajax result...

Now to your actual Problem: You want to get the element called "resultFromFile1" that's inside file2.php but you aren't adding anything to the "visible scope" yet since Load only loads the content but it doesn't add the content to any element you have to define an element holding your "file2.php". If i were you to avoid all these Problems i would use AngularJS for displaying your data in to a view and just include your "result" template via ng-include and let the ajax fill the document..

To solve your Problem:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
// Your Solution
function myAjax () {
    $.ajax( { type : 'POST',
      data : { },
      url  : 'query.php',
      success: function ( data ) {
        $doc = new DomDocument();
        $doc->Load('file2.php');
        $element = $doc->getElementById('resultFromFile1');
      },
      error: function ( xhr ) {
        alert( "error" );
      }
    });
}

// My Solution for this problem using native js

// Load the "file2" contents in to the file2Holder element
LoadUrlToElement('file2.php','file2Holder',function(data){

    /* When the first loading of file2.php is done, load the results from the query.php and put it in to the element called "resultFromFile1" which we just loaded and placed in to the dom before. But i would recommend you to use AngularJS to avoid this Callback hell and get many cool features that webdevelopers don't want to miss these days.... */

    LoadUrlToElement('query.php','resultFromFile1',function(){
        alert('Content of resultFromFile1 is => '+document.getElementById('resultFromFile1'));
    });
});

function LoadUrlToElement(url,elementID,done) {
    $.ajax( { type : 'POST',
      data : { },
      url  : url,
      success: function ( data ) {
          if(document.getElementById(elementID) === undefined){
          alert("Can't proceed cause the content holder"+elementID+" is not found");
              return; // Abort here cause there is no container with this id...
          }
          document.getElementById(elementID).html = data;
          if(done !== undefined && typeof done === 'function') done(data);
      },
      error: function ( xhr ) {
        alert( "error" );
      }
    });
}
</script>
<div id="file2Holder"></div>
```